# What values can $p$ take in a geometric distribution?

Tags: probability

If $Y$ is a geometric distribution, then
$$
P(Y=y)=(1-p)^{y-1}p
$$
What values can $p$ take? can it take the values $0$ and $1$? or it only needs to be $0<p<1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p=0$, that is the probability of success is $0$, then we will have to take infinitely trials.

If $p=1$, then $P(Y=1)=1$. However if you substitue the number in, we get $0^0$, hence it is better to handle this case separately.

In these cases, the model is deterministic.